# How to get individual value that doesn't consider last month's value and give output result in 2 criteria month and Name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to get unique outlet billed per month, the next month shouldn't include the outlets that were billed last month. Also incorporate Salesmen wise to be the criteria.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktESL.png)

I tried using lambda but able to get it only month wise unique outlet but want month wise and Salesman wise in the matrix shown in the image.

```
=BYCOL( TRANSPOSE( UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$B$2:$B$51)),
        LAMBDA(bymonth,
        SUMPRODUCT( N( XLOOKUP( UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$C$2:$C$51),
                                'Raw Data'!$C$2:$C$51,
                                'Raw Data'!$B$2:$B$51,
                                ,0)
                       =bymonth))))
```